# C# WinForm Controls > Forms control to cycle through records?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Hey all.  To be honest, I don't prefer MS Access as a relational database management system (RDBMS).  Except, in the forms view part of Access, it had move-forward/jump-to-the-end and move-backward/jump-to-the-beginning buttons at the bottom right/left (respectively).

I was hoping to mimic that functionality in C# with my XML Editing Form.  Is there already a form control (freely available) that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the BindingNavigator control, which is already included.

You haven't said what version of Visual Studio you are running.  This answer assumes VS2008.  There is a comprable control in VS2K5, but the name escapes me right now and I am no longer running VS2K5 on any of my PCs.